# SQL Count distinct per 30 days

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

Can SQL distinct count per 30 days backward or MAU (Monthly active user)? for example if I have data like this:

```
date          user
1/1/2020      A
1/2/2020      B
1/2/2020      C
...
1/30/2020     Z
```

And I transform it into like this using DISTINCT COUNT

```
date          distinct_user
1/1/2020      1
1/2/2020      2
...
1/30/2020     30
```

To make it easier, assume that distinct user is the number of distinct users that active per days and there is no overlap between days (in reality there is overlap). So the result of MAU will be like this

```
date          distinct_user     MAU
1/1/2020      1                 1
1/2/2020      2                 3
...
1/30/2020     30                465
```

465 is the result of calculating distinct user in 30 days (with assumption no overlap user every days). so if there is 5 new user that active on 1/31/2020, the result will be like this

```
date          distinct_user     MAU
1/1/2020      1                 1
1/2/2020      2                 3
...
1/30/2020     30                465
1/31/2020     5                 469
```

469 is from (Last MAU) + (new distinct user) - (distinct user from 1/1/2020 because the range is 30 days) so the result is 465 + 5 - 1 with the assumption that 5 users that active on 1/31/2020 is not active from 1/2/2020 to 1/30/2020

Comment: The problem I see is that you don't have information about the users that visited the site on a specific date. How you know that the users that visited you on Jan 30th are not that same that visited on the 31st ? If you have this info, the query is just a trivial SELECT COUNT (DISTINTICT user_id) FROM ....

Comment: oops my bad, i will edit my post

Answer (score 1):

There are different approches to answer this question, the better one in terms of performance may be the following :

```
SELECT mt1.`date`, SUM(mt2.distinct_user) AS MAU
FROM (
    SELECT `date`
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY `date`
) mt1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `date`, SUM(distinct_user) AS distinct_user
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY `date`
) mt2
WHERE mt2.`date` BETWEEN mt1.`date` - INTERVAL 29 DAY AND mt1.`date` 
GROUP BY mt1.`date`
ORDER BY mt1.`date`;
```

[**SEE DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bd2eaad824101a96e5c3c6639bd4bf5b)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest method is to "unpivot" the data and reaggregate:

```
with t1 as (
      select date, user, 1 as inc
      from t
      union all
      select date + interval 30 day, user, -1 as inc
      from t
     ),
select date,
       sum(case when sum_inc > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as running_30day_users
from (select t1.*,
             sum(inc) over (partition by user order by date) as sum_inc
      from t1
     ) t1
group by date;
```

I should note that this can also be expressed in SQL as:

```
select distinct date, running_30
from (select t.*,
             count(distinct user) over (order by date range between interval 29 day preceding and current date) as running_30
      from t
     ) t;
```

However, I'm not sure if Athena supports that syntax.